What are the different types of instant coffee?
What are the commonly available different types of instant coffee, and what's the difference in each of them?
I'm currently living somewhere without a way to make coffee, but there's a few dozen options of instant coffee available at the market. The most obvious difference that I can see in the different types of instant coffee is that some are granulated and some are not granulated, but I'm sure there's other differences as-well (which I simply cannot see just with the naked eye).








Granulated instant coffee is visibly different from non-granulated instant coffee -- you can see the large grains with the naked eye (source)



I've tried searching the 'net for this, but all the results that I come-across describe the difference between instant coffee and non-instant coffee. I'm asking here only about the difference between different types of instant coffee. I'm not asking for a comparison of different brands of instant coffee. I'm asking about the different types (of manufacturing of) instant coffee.
What are the most common types of instant coffee, how are they made, and how does each compare?

See also https://coffeestrides.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-its-made-instant-coffee.html

Instant espresso powder does seem different - just about good enough to use in baking. But I don't know if the process is significantly different to normal instant. Then there are the instant types that have a bit of extremely finely ground coffee in them as well. More expensive, not really much better.

I'd guess that they all use more or less the same process and the differences are entirely down to how finely they break up the final product - wikipedia tells me some are freeze dried and others spray dried, which would give final grain size differences. It might well come under the heading of "industrial secret" as I'm sure you would need to ask the manufacturers as to how they actually do it.

@SnakeDoc While comments are used for some less-directly-on-topic purposes, they are not a place for extended discussion, nor do they constitute carte blanche permission to go as off-topic as you like. Specifically, the OP very clearly chose to ask an informational question about types and attributes of instant coffee, and our job is to respect that and address it, not to try to judge the overall quality of instant coffee or discuss other types of coffee. I'd suggest stepping away from this question.

paging @tetsujin, who seems to know quite a bit about instant coffee

@j4nd3r53n, I sometimes use instant coffee to make cold coffee, no boiling involved: dissolve the powder/granules in tap water, add milk (or cream or half-and-half), stir. Granted, I do have the means to make coffee from ground coffee, but my point is that this does not necessarily follow from my ability to make instant coffee.

@j4nd3r53n information about non-instant-coffee is off-topic. This is exactly why I created this question, because it's extremely hard to find information only about instant coffee. Please stay on-topic.

Any discussion of instant coffee is incomplete without this SNL commercial for Foldger's Crystals: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmVnbIwBsfU

@MichaelAltfield "paging @tetsujin" just wanted to let you know that users (and even mods/staff) cannot ping anyone who hasn't commented on the post. You might either ping/invite them from the chat (kind of acceptable), or comment on any of their post directly (very discouraged).

So we're just not going to select an answer out of spite now?

The options I'm aware of:

freeze-dried (which typically results in the "granules") - frozen,
then placed under vacuum to remove the water

and

spray-dried (which is more just a fine powder) - liquid sprayed at the
top of a column where warm dry air is being (rather gently) blown in the bottom and
the droplets are dried to specks of powder as they fall.

Freeze dried is generally considered to be somewhat better (since less heating of the coffee is involved), as instant coffee goes. But as a matter of taste, try and see which you prefer, that's what actually matters to you.
Within each process type there may be differences you taste due to bean selection and how the coffee is roasted and brewed at the factory, or process parameters of the drying process. That tends to be submerged in a tide of marketing, and not really divulged in any detail; so listen to your own taste with regards to "better/worse." Most of "dozens of types" is really multiple brands (some probably made by the same company in the same factory - and possibly only the labels differ) of the two types.

I've wiped the comments. Please be kind, as the rules request, and in particular if you think something is wrong with the question don't take it out on people writing answers.

Your answer could be improved by focusing on the attributes in that paragraph about what people often consider "better." I think it's probably mostly just a matter of connecting the dots a bit: less heating of coffee means... more original flavor preserved?

Good answer +1. An important aspect of instant coffee is whether it is made from arabica or robusta coffee; personally, I find arabica by far the better, but it is a bit more expensive.

Sometimes what is sold as "instant  espresso" or whatever might already have added sugar or powdered milk, so beware of that.

for sure you have to taste it to see what you like. I personally prefer a brand of instant coffee that's spray dried over the common freeze-dried ones I've tried.

A slight issue is that there is also agglomerated instant coffee, in effect spray-dried coffee powder stuck together into small lumps to make it look a little more like freeze-dried coffee. It may also affect the flavour slightly.

I wonder if the method of drying accounts for the only practical (that is, measurable or visible) difference I've found between various brands or types: how well they dissolve in not-hot liquid. Which method is typically used for instant espresso? That type usually dissolves fairly easily in cool liquid.
